# Find the greatest increase value in a Map

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am at the beginning of my Scala journey. I am trying to find and compare the highest increased value of a given dataset - type Map(String, List[Int]). The program should calculate the increase(or decrease) between the 7th last value of the List ant the last value of each row and then print the highest increase row of the entire Map. For example, given the following dataset:

```
DATASET
SK1, 9, 7, 2, 0, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1

SK2, 0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1

SK3, 8, 7, 1, 8, 0, 5, 8, 3, 5, 9, 7, 5, 4, 7, 9, 8, 1, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 3, 6, 8, 8, 7, 4, 0, 7
```

The program should calculate the increase of each row:

```
SK1 = 1 "last value" - 5 "7th last value" = - 4
SK2 = 1 "last value" - 4 "7th last value" = - 3
SK3 = 7 "last value" - 6 "7th last value" = 1
```

The program should then print SK3 - 0 because is the highest increase.

The program can calculate the the increase of each row but it currently needs an SK input with the following two methods:

```scala
def rise(stock: String): (Int) = {
    mapdata.get(stock).map(findLast(_)).getOrElse(0) -
    (mapdata.get(stock).map(_.takeRight(7).head.toInt).getOrElse(0))
}
```

```scala
def stockRise(stock: String): (String, Int) = {
    (stock, rise(stock))
}
```

The two methods are then called within the program menu using:

```scala
def handleFive(): Boolean = {
    menuShowSingleDataStock(stockRise)
    true
}
```

```scala
//Pull two rows from the dataset
def menuShowDoubleDataStock(resultCalculator: (String, String) => (String, Int)) = {
    print("Please insert the Stock > ")
    val stockName1 = readLine
    print("Please insert the Stock > ")
    val stockName2 = readLine
    val result = resultCalculator(stockName1, stockName2)
    println(s"${result._1}: ${result._2}")
}
```

I have tried to call the following method that calculates the rises of every row using the following method but it doesn't seem to be working:

```scala
def menuShowStocks(f: () => Map[String, List[Int]]) = {
    val highestIncrese = 0
    f() foreach { case (x, y) => println(s"$x: $y") }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the input format? I don't get what the numbers on the lines are supposed to mean.

Comment: The system is taking the numbers on the screen that are on a file and it is saving them as a Map(String, List[Int]). Example HashMap(SK1 -> List(2, 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 0, 8, 5, 9, 0, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6, 7, 7, 0, 9, 5, 2, 5, 0, 2, 1, 8, 6), SK2 -> List(7, 1, 8, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 7, 4, 0, 6, 9, 5, 5, 4, 9, 1, 8, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 7, 9, 7, 2, 6, 6)

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is:

- first map each row, calculate the score
- use an aggregation function to select the desired row

Here we go:

```scala
scala> val dataSet = Map(
     |   "SK1" -> List(9, 7, 2, 0, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1),
     |   "SK2" -> List(0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1),
     |   "SK3" -> List(8, 7, 1, 8, 0, 5, 8, 3, 5, 9, 7, 5, 4, 7, 9, 8, 1, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 3, 6, 8, 8, 7, 4, 0, 7)
     | )
val dataSet: Map[String, List[Int]] = Map(SK1 -> List(9, 7, 2, 0, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1), SK2 -> List(0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1), SK3 -> List(8, 7, 1, 8, 0, 5, 8, 3, 5, 9, 7, 5, 4, 7, 9, 8, 1, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 3, 6, 8, 8, 7, 4, 0, 7))

scala> val highestIncrease = dataSet
     |   .toSeq
     |   .map { case (name, ints) =>
     |     name -> (ints.last - ints(ints.length - 7))
     |   }
     |   .maxBy(_._2)
val highestIncrease: (String, Int) = (SK3,1)
```

Some notes:

- The map is converted to a Seq first with `toSeq`. Mapping over Map's is entirely possible but a bit more complicated. Better leave this for a later learning moment. This produces a `Seq[(String, List[Int])]`.
- Using `map` we iterate over the tuples in the Seq. This uses pattern matching to extract the variables `name` and `ints`.
- The score is calculated. Also, we use the `->` operator to construct a new tuple of 2 items so we hang on to the name of the row.
- Method `maxBy` accepts a function to get a value. The expression `_._2`, equivalent to `x => x._2` is a function that gives the second value in each tuple.

The following could print the name of what we found:

```scala
println(s"The highest increase is in dataset ${highestIncrease._1} and is ${highestIncrease._2}.")
```